# can.Model destroy with multiple parameters

Tags: canjs, canjs-model

I'm working with an API over which I have no control.  I would like to do something like this:

```
var Page = can.Model.extend({
  destroy: 'DELETE /api/{account_id}/{page_id}'
})
```

This doesn't work - canjs simply doesn't use the destroy URL.  I tried creating a function, but the only param passed is the 'id'.  I'm sure you'll say that this is not really REST, but I'm stuck with the API.  Any time I put more than one param into the url, the url is not used.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually setting the *prototype* destroy property to a string here, because the first object passed to extend() is interpreted as the prototype properties if a second object is not passed. You actually need to do this: 

    `var Page = can.Model.extend({
       destroy: 'DELETE /api/{account_id}/{page_id}'
    }, {})`

(NB: CanJS internally converts `destroy` and some other properties from AJAX specs to functions when you extend can.Model, but *only* in the static properties)

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is OK (took a while to figure out that the 2nd parameter is the instance... didn't see that documented anywhere):

```
var Page = can.Model.extend({
  destroy: function(id, page) {
    return $.get('/api/'+page.account_id+'/'+page.id);
  }
})
```

Which seems a bit weird, but I'll get over it!